# Some clarification about how ant copy some files into a folder?

Tags: java, ant

I am pretty new to ant (I came from Maven and Ant is a nightmare for me !!!)

I have this target:

```
<target name="linuxdriver"
    description="Linux Driver">
    <copy file="${deps.linuxdriver.dir}/${deps.linuxdriver.name}" tofile="${project.datadir}/${deps.linuxdriver.name}"/>
    <copy file="${deps.linuxdriver.dir}/${deps.linuxdriver.name}" tofile="${project.deploy}/data/${deps.linuxdriver.name}"/>
    <chmod perm="+x" file="${project.datadir}/${deps.linuxdriver.name}"/>
    <chmod perm="+x" file="${project.deploy}/data/${deps.linuxdriver.name}"/>
</target>
```

and I have also a **property file** in which there is definied the "variable" (are named variable?) used in the previous ant code, specifically I have:

> **project.datadir         = ${basedir}/data**
>
> **project.deploy.dir      = Release**
>
> **project.deploy          = ${basedir}/../${project.deploy.dir}**

And now I have some doubts:

1) What represents **${basedir}**? A specific directory? What?

2) Using the previous information what exactly are the two destination folder in which the files are copied (using the "copy file...to file" tag)?

Comment: I don't see where you're defining `${deps.linuxdriver.name}`.  But if you look in your ant build.xml, your `project` tag is where basedir is defined.  From my project, `<project name="MyProj" basedir="." default="deploy">`.  Using `.` as your basedir means the current directory.

Comment: They use the term "property" rather than "variable".  This is worth noting because properties in Ant are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

That concept of basedir is described in the ANT manual:

- [Built-in properties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html)
- [Writing a simple Buildfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html)

It's normally set to be the directory from where you run the build (can be overridden).

If you need to see how properties are resolved, consider running your build in [debug mode](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)